# How to I use my own interface with OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel?

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous

see also [Why do I get InvalidCastException from OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<>()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808598/why-do-i-get-invalidcastexception-from-operationcontext-current-getcallbackchanne)

I wish to pass my own interface to OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel, as I wish to make Asynchronous calls to the client(s) and hence need to add the “BeginMethod()” etc to the interface.

I can anexception saying it can’t cast to the interface if I pass any interface apart from the one that is named in the ServiceContract for the server I am implementing.

E.g. I have

```
<ServiceContract(CallbackContract:=GetType(IClient))>
```

On the server contract

And a interface defined as a subclass of IClient that adds the “BeginMethod()” etc, but I can’t ask for that interface from:

```
 OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientWithAsycMethods>()
```

Comment: I have voted to close my own question as another question I asked lead to the same answer, however I don't want this questions deleted as it may help someone that finds it with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Why do I get InvalidCastException from OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<>()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808598/why-do-i-get-invalidcastexception-from-operationcontext-current-getcallbackchanne)